# Structured data how to loop and add items

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a way to add my products to a structured data itemList. As the example below shows a couple of products that are already added but in my case the items are dynamicly added, well I want to add them thru a loop but not sure how to add item to the list

**What I want to do**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

​{
  "@context":"https://schema.org",
  "@type":"ItemList",
  "itemListElement":[

      // as example on what i am trying to do(yes this is not going to work)
      $('.item').each(function(e,i){
          "url": $(this).attr('href');
          ...
      });

  ]
}
</script>
```

**How it should be**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

​{
  "@context":"https://schema.org",
  "@type":"ItemList",
  "itemListElement":[
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":1,
      "url":"http://example.com/coffee_cake.html"
    },
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":2,
      "url":"http://example.com/apple_pie.html"
    },
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":3,
      "url":"http://example.com/blueberry-pie.html"
    },
   {...}
  ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to to assign an `id` to your script, e.g. `schemaDesc`

```js
<script type="application/ld+json" id="schemaDesc">

​{
  "@context":"https://schema.org",
  "@type":"ItemList",
  "itemListElement":[
   {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":1,
      "url":"http://example.com/coffee_cake.html"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

and then parse it's data, add new items to any properties you need, and then update the scripts data back like this:

```js
const scriptEl = document.getElementById('schemaDesc')
const schemaObj = JSON.parse(scriptEl.innerHTML);

schemaObj.itemListElement = [
   ...schemaObj.itemListElement,
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":2,
      "url":"http://example.com/apple_pie.html"
    },
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":3,
      "url":"http://example.com/blueberry-pie.html"
    },
];

scriptEl.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(schemaObj, null, 2);
```

that would update your script with required data.